# Which desktop manager to use in 19.04

Tags: desktop-environments, 19.04

After I upgraded from Ubuntu 18.10 to 19.04, several desktop managers started to appear in my login screen:

[image]

Which one should I use normally?

My questions:

- Which of these are going to be deprecated?
- How do I eliminate the unneeded ones safely?

Comment: Why not try them, to see which one you like? There's even many more to try, such as KDE and xfce.

Comment: My question was a theoretical one. I know that each one has its pros and cons and these are subjective things. However, I wanted to learn which one is pushed by Canonical and which ones are going to be killed by Canonical in the future.

Comment: I'd focus on using the one you like, and not worry about them getting killed off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of April 2019, there is no plan to deprecate any of them.

The most likely to survive over the long term is GNOME (plain GNOME).

- GNOME Classic is merely a the Gnome desktop without the Ubuntu modifications. Some folks prefer this experience.
- GNOME on XORG is merely a fallback option for folks who don't have complete Wayland compatibility yet.
- Ubuntu is the popular, community-maintained Unity desktop built on top of Gnome. Some folks prefer this experience.
- Ubuntu on Wayland is for folks who have complete Wayland compatibility.

Comment: OK. I will try to stick to the first option (**plain GNOME**). Is there any reason to keep or not to keep the others? And, how do I remove them?

Comment: The first option (**plain GNOME**) removes the window title from some applications (namely Firefox and Thunderbird) which makes impossible to move these applications to other workspaces (by right clicking on the title bar and selecting **Move to Workspace ...**)

Comment: The **GNOME** session has also the drag-and-drop problem described in: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1136203/drag-and-drop-functionality-no-longer-working-after-upgrade-to-19-04

Comment: After upgrading to 19.10, now I have only three options: **GNOME on Xorg**, **GNOME Classic**, and **Ubuntu**. **GNOME on Xorg** works just OK, and does _not_ have any of the problems mentioned in this post.