# Why can't I copy from VMware guest to Ubuntu host, while I can do the reverse (from Ubuntu to Windows 7 guest)

Tags: windows-7, virtualization, vmware

I am currently using Ubuntu 19.04 and using VMware for virtualization.

In a virtual machine I am running Windows 7 and I installed `VMware Tools` on Windows 7. The problem is that I can copy anything from my Ubuntu host to Windows 7 guest, but I *cannot* copy things from my Windows 7 guest and paste to Ubuntu host.

Comment: Not an answer to your question. But, did you consider using **VirtualBox**? It runs much more seamlessly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer , I will install VirtualBox and test it

Comment: You can use your previously created VMDK *virtual disk files* directly in VirtualBox also.

Comment: Copying and pasting files from Windows run in VMware to Ubuntu works fine for me, and vice-versa. Are you pasting to a (sub)folder in your user account?

Comment: @Paul Benson it worked fine for me too , until yesterday that I installed the new version of UBUNTU(19.04) , and after that I can only copy pasting from Ubuntu to vm , not the reverse , and I've tried sub folder and main folder both , none of them worked !

Comment: @FedonKadifeli it's funny , also with VirtualBox I can't copy past from real host to vm , I installed guest addition , but it didn't work , I think it's about ubuntu 19.04 , because every thing works fine on ubuntu 18.10

Comment: @Afshin I never tried before (in 18.10) to copy and paste **files** from/to guest to/from host or to drag and drop files. So, I cannot say whether it worked in previous versions of Ubuntu, but *certainly it does not work in 19.04*. Note: Ubuntu itself has some problems with DnD (See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1136203/drag-and-drop-functionality-no-longer-working-after-upgrade-to-19-04/1146765). Note also that my session is: `XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland` and `XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP=gnome`. _However, copying and pasting **text** does work both ways._

Comment: x11 is the output of echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE