# Trying out wayland

Tags: kubuntu, xorg, kde, laptop, wayland

I noticed somewhere (on the login screen IIRC) that you can choose between Wayland and xorg
Is it safe to do so? I won't get into a situation where Wayland can't start or crashes, but then I cannot access the computer to fix the problem by setting it back to xorg, (which works fine), I am just nosy to see what all the fuss is about. Maybe the laptop will be faster with wayland or something?

Thanks!

Comment: Every display protocol has its pros and cons. If something works, don't change it.

Comment: You can always select the other protocol (Xorg) on the login screen. So, if you encounter a problem or something that does not work as you expected or are accustomed to, you can log out and log in with Xorg. See also this: https://askubuntu.com/a/1136172/855322

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For most users, Wayland has been "safe to do so" (suitable for production use) since about 2017. It was in development and testing for a decade before that. It's not unstable.

For a few, it remains not suitable. If your Ubuntu system detects that your hardware is incompatible with Wayland, then you won't be offered the choice. For even fewer, there are still bugs being worked...as there are in all complex projects (including Xorg).

You are unlikely to notice much difference in performance.

Comment: However, there may be some minor _feature_ (you can call them _bug_) differences between the two protocols. Personally, I still cannot trust the Wayland choice and I am still using Xorg.