# Ubuntu gdm3 login screen menu

Tags: gnome, 22.04, login, gdm, ubuntu-budgie

I have gdm3 installed as my `display-manager` on Ubuntu Budgie and when I log in there is this small settings icon in the right corner with the options:

```
Ubuntu Budgie

Ubuntu

Ubuntu with Xorg
```

What are their diffrences and which one is the better one? How did ubuntu end up on my PC? Does Ubuntu come with Ubuntu budgie or the other way around?

Comment: xorg is old. others use wayland as display manager

Comment: I still use Xorg. See also this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1136127/which-desktop-manager-to-use-in-19-04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The options you see on the login screen, such as "Ubuntu Budgie," "Ubuntu," and "Ubuntu with Xorg," are different desktop environments or sessions that you can choose to log into.

- **Ubuntu Budgie**: This is the default session for Ubuntu Budgie, which is a flavor of Ubuntu featuring the Budgie desktop environment. It provides a clean and user-friendly interface.
- **Ubuntu**: This typically refers to the default session for standard Ubuntu, which uses the GNOME desktop environment. GNOME is another popular desktop environment for Linux.
- **Ubuntu with Xorg**: This is an option that allows you to use the Xorg display server instead of the default Wayland. Wayland and Xorg are display server protocols, and the choice between them can depend on factors like hardware compatibility and specific use cases.

As for how Ubuntu ended up on your PC, Ubuntu Budgie is an official flavor of Ubuntu. It means that it's an Ubuntu variant that features the Budgie desktop environment. When you installed Ubuntu Budgie, it brought the Ubuntu base along with it.

The choice between these sessions depends on your preferences:

- If you like the Budgie desktop environment, you can stick with "Ubuntu Budgie."
- If you prefer the default GNOME experience, you can choose "Ubuntu."
- The "Ubuntu with Xorg" option might be useful if you encounter issues with **Wayland** or if you have specific requirements that are better supported by **Xorg**.